# C# - Disable button if string empty or has whitespace?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, user-interface

I just started learning C#.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object Nappi1 = ("Nice button");
    MessageBox.Show(Nappi1.ToString());
}
```

I got a textbox, that should disable the `button1` if empty or whitespace.

I already got it working in some level, but it checks the state of the `textbox` on `button1_Click`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1 = "") 
    {
        button1.enabled = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        button1.enabled = true;
        object Nappi1 = ("Nice button");
        MessageBox.Show(Nappi1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Fictional example:

```
 if (textBox1 = "" or textBox1 = whitespace[s])
```

---

1. How could I make it check the state of the `textbox` `onLoad` (as soon as the program starts)?
2. How could I make it check if (multiple) `whitespace`, and can I write it to the same `if` -statement?

Please keep it simple.

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: I know you're just starting, but nevertheless I think it would be best to take a closer look at objects and properties as well as some of the most common notifying mechanisms like INotifyProperty, it will definitely make your life way easier once you get used to it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer exactly the question title, Shorter, clearer:

```
button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace your if-else with this, if it is only a `string`:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1)) {
    button1.enabled = false;
}
else {
    button1.enabled = true;
    ...
}
```

or use `textBox1.Text` if it is really a `Textbox` use this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) {
    button1.enabled = false;
}
else {
    button1.enabled = true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) {
    button1.enabled = false;
}
```

You originally had:

```
if (textBox1 = "") {
button1.enabled = false;
}
```

`textbox` is the control, you need to use the `Text` property which refers to the string literal inside the textbox control.  Also in C# `=` is an assignment, you ideally would want `==` which is used to compare.

If you're not using `.NET 4` or `.NET 4.5` you can use:

[String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using hooking an event handler to text-box text changed event. 
Steps:

1. Attach an event handler for text-box (on text changed)
   Inside the text changed event handler enable / disable the button.

   `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
               button1.Enabled = false;
           else
               button1.Enabled = true;
       }`
2. By default disable the button in InitializeComponent method of form

   `button1.Enabled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

In the textBox1 text changed event, right this code:

```
button1.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text);
```

string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("some text") will check if the text is none or just a wightspaces
if this is true you will set button1.Enabled to false.